# Triangle artifacts appear on rendered result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

thx in advance.

When I render the rendered output has triangular artifacts not visible in the viewport even with the same samples.

Left side is Cycles Rendered Image, 128 samples, right side is Viewport, 128 samples.

My rendered output has the triangle artifacts and I want to get rid of them. They are not present on the texture image so they are something blender adds.
I've tried the various Texture Interpolations in the Image Texture Shader.  I've also played around with the UV map.  What else might cause/eliminate this?

[image]

Comment: This looks a bit like Z-fighting, although I would imagine there would be more of those strange artifacts if it was that. You are sure there is no second sphere in the same size which has visibilty disabled in viewport but is visible in render?

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  That might be a useful tidbit - I did accidentally have that and removed it, before I noticed this problem so I know what you are saying.  I def do not have that now ... but along those lines I do have several spheres here - Earth, Clouds and Atmosphere.  Maybe they are just a tad too close or intersect.  I rendered each layer separately (turned off render for other layers) and determined that this happens even when ONLY the earth layer is rendered, so the culprit seems to be there somewhere.  I've applied all transformations.  Maybe I need to change scale a tad.

Comment: Yup this is on the right track.  I had a duplicated object for a moon, that somehow ended back up at the origin despite moving it aside.  I scaled it down and moved it again.  But I still have the problem, now isolated to Earth and Cloud layer.  They must be too close.

Comment: Resolved!  Thx Gordon!  I guess my duplicated sphere (which I move aside) keeps moving back to same physical space when I move the animation slider.    I've moved, scaled, applied all transformation and update animation and those artifacts are gone!